# Nested array manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I have below two array:

```
var val = [['aa', 'ab', 'ac'], ['bb', 'bc', 'bd']];
var key = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
```

By using any javascript logic I want to get a new array in below format.

```
[
  {item1: 'aa', item2: 'ab', item3: 'ac'},
  {item1: 'bb', item2: 'bc', item3: 'bd'}
]
```

I tried using .forEach and `.map()` to achieve this, but somehow I couldn't able to do it.

Here is the sample code I tried.https://plnkr.co/edit/oKyjNsBu3wrRin7TaCIb?p=preview

```
var val = [['aa', 'ab', 'ac'], ['bb', 'bc', 'bd']];
var key = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
var newArr = val.map((elm,i)=>{
  return {[key[i]]: elm[i]}
})
console.log('newArr', newArr);
```

I need the output as below.

```
[
  {item1: 'aa', item2: 'ab', item3: 'ac'},
  {item1: 'bb', item2: 'bc', item3: 'bd'}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods to get the desired output:

```js
const vals = [['aa','ab','ac'],['bb','bc','bd']];
const keys = ['item1','item2','item3'];

const result = vals.map((val) => keys.reduce((r, c, i) => (r[c] = val[i], r), {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Map the `val` array (change its name to `allVals` for better clarity) to objects using `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
var allVals = [['aa','ab','ac'],['bb','bc','bd']];
var keys = ['item1','item2','item3'];

const output = allVals.map(vals => Object.fromEntries(
  vals.map((val, i) => [keys[i], val])
));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const values = [['aa','ab','ac'],['bb','bc','bd']];
const keys = ['item1','item2','item3'];

const result = values.map(v => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, v[i]])));

console.log(result);
```